# React app netlify deployment version errors. (Make netlify use npm install --force instead of npm install)

Tags: reactjs, deployment, npm-install, netlify, react-scripts

I use a package called react-comments-section in my application which is compatible with node 16 only. My other packages are compatible with node 18. Locally, i use npm install --force to resolve all the conflicts and the application works just fine. But when I try to run on netlify, it uses npm install only and hence my project cannot initialize.

i tried writing build and prebuild script in package.json  for npm install --force
I also tried making a netlify.toml file and specify npm install --force in the build configuration but it didn't work. Do you have any solutions???
package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "npm install --force",
  "build": "npm run build"
}
```

netlify.toml

```
[build]
  command = "npm run prebuild && npm run build"
```

error

> 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: 11:22:42 AM:
> npm ERR! peer react@^16.0.0 from react-comments-section@2.0.10
> 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-comments-section 11:22:42 AM:
> npm ERR!   react-comments-section@^2.0.10 from the root project
> 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR! 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer
> dependency: react@16.14.0 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
> 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@^16.0.0 from
> react-comments-section@2.0.10 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-comments-section 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR!
> react-comments-section@^2.0.10 from the root project 11:22:42 AM: npm
> ERR! 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or
> retry 11:22:42 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force or
> --legacy-peer-deps